# Uploaded images do not appear in web

Tags: php, javascript, text, editor, tinymce

I have been working on a small product based site. This site has various products and descriptions along with images in it. I am using tinymce editor to upload the description and images.

But the problem is, when I copy-paste the image in the editor, it shows fine in localserver but in web it shows a sign like this `\"\"` and the url associated with the image is like: `http://abc.com.au/products/\"abc.com.au/admin/data/test.jpg\"`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you paste EXACTLY what you are pasting into the editor, use the {} tools in stackoverflow's editor to make it a code block

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are saving the content from the editor window to a database, you need to use the `stripslashes` function on the string you pass from the editor to the database. That way, the content won't be altered. The slashes are added by default since characters like double quotes need to be escaped in order for the code to be parsed, as well as displayed, correctly.